# Is there a way to send low res binary images to mobile phones using the USSD protocol?

Tags: ota, ussd

Is there a way to send low res binary images to mobile phones using the USSD protocol? I know that OTA bitmap allows us to send similar images through SMS; however, I could not find anything on USSD that details this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. USSD does not have any defined methods to specify content type, nor does it really support segmentation and reassembly  of even small binary data sequences. It might be possible given operator cooperation to do something that worked but itwould be a bad hack and probably not very widely distributable